# Can I run an emulator without HAXM in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device, haxm

In Eclipse I can run an emulator without `HAXM` but when I want to run the emulator without `HAXM` in Android Studio, I get an error `intel haxm is required to run this avd`

Can I run the emulator without `HAXM` in Android Studio for  a device not supporting it?
And how?

**Update 1:**

[image]

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The Android emulator is independent from Android Studio and Eclipse.

HAXM is Intel's virtualization extension for Android Emulator on x86. You can use an emulator with the ARM image instead of HAXM provided that you installed it in the SDK manager.

Check your SDK manager to see if you have an ARM image instead for the API level you want,  then go to the AVD manager and make a virtual device using ARM as the cpu.

Comment: thank your for answer. question is updated!, i have 2 ARM image `1.ARM EABI v7a System Image` and `2.Google API ARM EABI v7a System Image` . which one must donwload?

Comment: Download the Google API ARM EABI V7A image. It will give you the basic android as well as extras like Google maps.

Comment: After downloading, go to the AVD manager and set up a device using the image you downloaded as the cpu

Comment: Big THX your tipp saved my day

Comment: Is this answer still valid in late 2020? I tried to apply the recommendation, but as a noob I'm having a hard time finding the `ARM image`

Comment: For me, choosing ARM image for an AVD does not work without HAXM on FreeBSD. Apparently it's required...

Answer (score 1):

Check your processor if its is Arm.download system image for arm in sdk manager

Answer (score 0):

For some processors, if you enable virtualization you should be able to run the android studio emulator without installing HAXM - for example on AMD you need to enable SVM mode