# How to launch an Android Simulator if my motherboard doesn't support it

Tags: android

I am unable to launch my Android App's simulation. I get the error:

> "Please ensure INTEL HAXM is properly installed and usable"
>
> "CPU acceleration status: HAX Kernel module is not installed!"

I installed the above mentioned modules and got the same results. Read around and was told that I need to activate the virtual simulation property from my BIOS only to realise my motherboard doesn't support it - no option for it. (I am using a MSI G43-Z87 Motherboard).

Is there any other way I could use a Virtual Simulator in my case (Free)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27472072/4428462).

From the link:

> HAXM is Intel's virtualization extension for Android Emulator on x86. You can use an emulator with the ARM image instead of HAXM provided that you installed it in the SDK manager.
>
> Check your SDK manager to see if you have an ARM image instead for the API level you want, then go to the AVD manager and make a virtual device using ARM as the cpu.

Answer (score 0):

Use your Android phone or tablet instead of Emulator. Emulator is unusable if your motherboard not support intel VT. Also can install VMBox or like. Also can buy new pc with core I7