# Android App crashes after splash screen

Tags: java, android, splash-screen

I am able to load the splash screen but after 3 seconds the app crashes.I want to load the Main Activity after the splash screen.Also I found that the same topic was discussed earlier in stack over flow but it didn't helped me.

Please help me solve the issues.

> AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.a2.attemp2" >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name=".SplashScreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.a2.MAINACTIVITY" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

> SplashScreen.java

```
package com.example.a2.attemp2;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Window;

public class SplashScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

//        //Remove title bar
//          this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
//
//        //Remove notification bar
//       // this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
//
//        //set content view AFTER ABOVE sequence (to avoid crash)
//        this.setContentView(R.layout.splash);


        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);

        Thread timerThread = new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                try{
                    sleep(3000);
                }catch(InterruptedException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }finally{
                    Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);

                    finish();
                }
            }
        };
        timerThread.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        finish();
    }

}
```

> MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.a2.attemp2;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

I had recently started another project with same code with different package com.example.jarvis.digin I assure you that there is no compilation errors.
```

> EVENT LOG

```
    10-17 21:46:20.887 7359-7359/com.example.jarvis.digin E/Trace: error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
10-17 21:46:21.347 7359-7359/com.example.jarvis.digin W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)
10-17 21:46:21.347 7359-7359/com.example.jarvis.digin I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onSearchRequested, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onSearchRequested
10-17 21:46:21.347 7359-7359/com.example.jarvis.digin W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 17898: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onSearchRequested (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)Z
10-17 21:46:21.347 7359-7359/com.example.jarvis.digin D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
10-17 21:46:21.347 7359-7359/com.example.jarvis.digin I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onWindowStartingActionMode, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onWindowStartingActionMode
10-17 21:46:21.347 7359-7359/com.example.jarvis.digin W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 17902: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onWindowStartingActionMode (Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
10-17 21:46:21.357 7359-7359/com.example.jarvis.digin D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
10-17 21:46:21.457 7359-7359/com.example.jarvis.digin D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
10-17 21:46:21.457 7359-7359/com.example.jarvis.digin W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x419a9300)
10-17 21:46:21.457 7359-7359/com.example.jarvis.digin E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-17 21:46:21.457 7359-7359/com.example.jarvis.digin E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.jarvis.digin/com.example.jarvis.digin.SplashScreen}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
10-17 21:46:21.457 7359-7359/com.example.jarvis.digin E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
10-17 21:46:21.457 7359-7359/com.example.jarvis.digin E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
10-17 21:46:21.457 7359-7359/com.example.jarvis.digin E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
10-17 21:46:21.457 7359-7359/com.example.jarvis.digin E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
10-17 21:46:21.457 7359-7359/com.example.jarvis.digin E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-17 21:46:21.457 7359-7359/com.example.jarvis.digin E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-17 21:46:21.457 7359-7359/com.example.jarvis.digin E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
10-17 21:46:21.457 7359-7359/com.example.jarvis.digin E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-17 21:46:21.457 7359-7359/com.example.jarvis.digin E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-17 21:46:21.457 7359-7359/com.example.jarvis.digin E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
10-17 21:46:21.457 7359-7359/com.example.jarvis.digin E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
10-17 21:46:21.457 7359-7359/com.example.jarvis.digin E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-17 21:46:21.457 7359-7359/com.example.jarvis.digin E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
10-17 21:46:21.457 7359-7359/com.example.jarvis.digin E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:311)
10-17 21:46:21.457 7359-7359/com.example.jarvis.digin E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280)
10-17 21:46:21.457 7359-7359/com.example.jarvis.digin E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:254)
10-17 21:46:21.457 7359-7359/com.example.jarvis.digin E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
10-17 21:46:21.457 7359-7359/com.example.jarvis.digin E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.jarvis.digin.SplashScreen.onCreate(SplashScreen.java:17)
10-17 21:46:21.457 7359-7359/com.example.jarvis.digin E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
10-17 21:46:21.457 7359-7359/com.example.jarvis.digin E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
10-17 21:46:21.457 7359-7359/com.example.jarvis.digin E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
10-17 21:46:21.457 7359-7359/com.example.jarvis.digin E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084) 
10-17 21:46:21.457 7359-7359/com.example.jarvis.digin E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130) 
10-17 21:46:21.457 7359-7359/com.example.jarvis.digin E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195) 
10-17 21:46:21.457 7359-7359/com.example.jarvis.digin E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
10-17 21:46:21.457 7359-7359/com.example.jarvis.digin E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
10-17 21:46:21.457 7359-7359/com.example.jarvis.digin E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
10-17 21:46:21.457 7359-7359/com.example.jarvis.digin E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
10-17 21:46:21.457 7359-7359/com.example.jarvis.digin E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
10-17 21:46:21.457 7359-7359/com.example.jarvis.digin E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
10-17 21:46:21.457 7359-7359/com.example.jarvis.digin E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
10-17 21:46:21.457 7359-7359/com.example.jarvis.digin E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: I am running generated apk file in a device without adt

because of this following issue
C:\Users\digin\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\emulator.exe -avd Nexus_5_API_23 -netspeed full -netdelay none
emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
CPU acceleration status: HAX kernel module is not installed!


So am unable to get stacktrace

Comment: change the image of the emulator from x86 to arm you can refer:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27471219/can-run-emulator-without-haxm-in-android-studio   or use the genymotion emulator...because without the logcat report it would be bit difficult to find out the reason for application crash

Comment: I installed google usb driver and was able to debug the application in device but still error occurs.I have updated the event log.

Comment: I was able to fix my problem by removing toolbar code from MainActivity.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error in your log was saying it was caused by:

IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.

I'd guess there is a problem with the theme you have specified in your AndroidManifest.xml.  Try changing it to something like:

android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo"

Check out [How to change app default theme to a different app theme?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19186235/how-to-change-app-default-theme-to-a-different-app-theme)

Answer (score 0):

This is the error message when running on the device

> This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor.
>   Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set
>   windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.

The problem is clear from the message above.

I solved this by removing the following code from `MainActivity.java`.

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Hope this answer will help beginners when they choose blank template.