# Android Studio Virtual Device on a Windows 7 VM not compatible

Tags: android, windows, android-studio, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I have a VirtualBox VM on my computer, the VM is running Windows 7 64bit. I installed Android Studio on that VM. I only have the basic Hello World application. When I try to run AVD I get this message:

> Intel HAXM is required to run this AVD. Android Emulator is
>   incompatible with Hyper-V.
>
> Unfortunately, you cannot have Hyper-V running and use the emulator.
>   Here is hat you can do:
>
> 1) Start a command prompt as Administrator
>
> 2) Run the following command: C:\Windows\system32> bcdedit /set
>   hypervisorlaunchtype off
>
> 3) Reboot your machine.

I tried running this command and restart multiple time, doesn't change anything.

I also tried to do some port forwarding : http://paulsdevworld.blogspot.ca/2013/06/make-android-studio-work-with-androvm.html 
I was unable to connect `No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.`

I've check this question, I'm not having the same issue because OP has a android image directly in VirtualBox [Test android app on Virtual Box from Android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28252296/test-android-app-on-virtual-box-from-android-studio)

Anyone knows a way to make this work or something that I could try?
Feel free to ask any question.

EDIT: 
I installed Intel HAXM but when I try to run it I get this message 
[image]

Those are my current settings, virtualization is clearly enabled. Is that the correct settings? [image]

Is there any way to make this work in a VM?

Starting a bounty the answer doesn't need to be with Virtual Box but has to be free of cost.

HOST PC 
[image: host]
GUEST PC
[image: guest]

I downloaded the free trial version of VMware and I manage to get it working using those settings below. I tried the exact same settings in VirtualBox and I get the Hyper-V error.
[image: settings screenshot]

**SOLUTION:**

If anyone is wondering I was able to run it in Virtual Box. 
This is the settings I used on the AVD: 
[image: Solution]
Warning slow.

Comment: Latest Android Studio targets only API 26 or 27. There isn't a corresponding arm image, last one is 25. So VirtualBox etc doesn't seem workable.

Comment: @James_UK_DEV You can use an older Android Studio version. I'm running version 2.2.2 right now

Comment: Installed latest on main machine and hoped for the best. Worked fine. I think a couple of pages suggested the older versions weren't available to try and put you off.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32308519/intel-haxm-installation-error-in-vmware

try this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read this post from virtual box as well and see if it applies to your situation please. :)
https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=69076. If this is the case I'm afraid that as you requested there would be no free option, as you may have to go for a software such as VMWare which is license based.

What you could otherwise do is **not** use Intel HAXM inside your existing VirtualBox. That is by using an Android image that does not need hardware acceleration. This is because it is not possible to run two different emulation stacks on your processor at the same time. So since you are already running Virtual Box it would be better to use an emulator that does not need hardware acceleration. You could refer this post:  [Can I run an emulator without HAXM in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27471219/can-run-emulator-without-haxm-in-android-studio)
if you like. Cheers

**EDIT: phil did you try this? It would seem like the only viable option since VMWare isn't free**

Comment: I did try this, still trying to find the right settings to make it work with arm. So far no luck

Comment: Do you know the exact settings with arm that would work?

Comment: @phil652 take a loot at [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30405740/android-studio-how-can-i-make-an-avd-with-arm-instead-of-haxm

Comment: So far I get this error: init: Could not find wglGetExtensionsStringARB! I'm still trying to get this resolved

Comment: @phil652 let me research on this as well. If I find something interesting I'll reply back

Comment: I'm playing with the settings in AVD. It seems that when I use arm, I need to set the Graphics to Software - GLES 2.0

Comment: Yes. Also just try out swapping settings with enabling and disabling host gpu settings. I'm not sure if this would solve since it's running inside a virtual box but may be worth a try.

Comment: I got it to work using arm, it just seems very slow, but it works! Thanks.

Comment: No problem. Glad to hear that Phil :)

Answer (score 5):

The below process works if your system supports Intel Virtualization Technology (VT-x):

1. Go to BIOS using <kbd>F10</kbd> on Boot-up.
2. Go to System Configuration/System Settings.
3. Enable Virtualization Technology.
4. Press <kbd>F10</kbd> to Save and Exit.
5. Reboot and your VT-x should be working.

Comment: I'm pretty sure VT-x feature is not for the guest OS, but for the host OS. I could be wrong.

Comment: Enabling VT-x from BIOS supports Host OS as well as Guest OS.

Comment: It's already enable. I updated my question to show that it doesn't work on the guest pc

Comment: Virtualization Technology for Guest PC can also be enabled from Virtual Machine Softwares like VMWare or VirtualBox once its enabled from BIOS.

Comment: What about the turn off Hyper-V issue, how do I fix that?

Comment: Go to Control Panel -> Programs and Features -> Turn Windows features on or off from **left pane** and enable/disable Hyper-V options.

Comment: This option is not available in my host and guest PC. Also I updated my question, I got it to work in VMware but I still have the same issue in VirtualBox

Comment: Check your system specifications on Intel website & if it supports Hyper-V, download the compatible Hyper-V installer from Intel website itself.

Comment: Can't find Hyper-V on the Intel website, Hyper-V is a Microsoft product.

Comment: Which edition of Windows are you using? "Home" version doesn't support Hyper-V at all. All other PC versions support Hyper-V only if they have 64-Bit architechture. Verify here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_10_editions#Comparison_chart

Comment: Host is running Windows 7 Enterprise and guest is Windows 7 pro

Comment: Is host 64-bit OS? Is your processor 64-bit?

Comment: Yes both 64bit.

Comment: Maybe Android is also refusing Hyper-V to be used, you can try downloading a pre-configured VM file and directly load it and use it instead of configuring one.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, solved it by Installing the Intel Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager. Download it with the SDK Manager, it's in Extras. After this, go to the folder

*`[Android SDK Root]`*`\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager`

then run `IntelHaxm.exe` and install.

Here the link of the Intel Hardware Accelerated
[IntelHaxm.exe](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager) for
Microsoft Windows,Mac OS* X, and Linux
Ubuntu

[image]

You'll get the following message if you don't have virtualization enabled in your BIOS:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I enabled virtualization in VirtualBox and re-installed HAXM and I get the same message just like the picture you posted

Comment: What are your settings for System>Acceleration in VirtualBox?

Comment: Enable VT-x/AMD-V and Enable Nested Paging both are checked.

Answer (score 1):

enable intel virtualization in bios

[image]

Answer (score 1):

if you've already enabled VT-x in the BIOS setting, make sure that you have installed intel haxm that comes with android sdk. If you haven't install it yet, you can open your SDK manager and install it from there or you can download it from this https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/extras/intel/addon/haxm-windows_r6_0_5.zip, unzip it to extras folder in your android sdk then install.

Comment: Oh my bad, please remove 'addon" from the link and it will automatically download intel haxm
 https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/extras/intel/haxm-windows_r6_0_5.zip

Comment: I get VT not supported error. Look at @sumeet screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try GenyMotion intead of AVD. It has better performance than AVD. It's free if you use it non-commercially. GenyMotion uses Virtual Box, you can check if VB working properly.

Comment: Does it has the same functionality as AVD? Is it easy to setup?

Comment: Yes, it may have more functionality than AVD, i haven't used AVD more than 6 months. It was definitely faster than AVD and consumes less CPU and your app starts faster. You can install Play Store to it, use it's phony camera to test, battery or location features. These are the most i use. It has a bundled setup like any other Windows program. After setup, you create Virtual devices using it's interface and add GM's plugin to Android Studio, select device from program's or plugin's interface. That's it. It's easy, and with better performance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are Not in situation to Enable `Intel-VT` from BIOS menu, You should use Different processors for your VM, like ARM or 32 bit processors. cause Intel-VT let's you use 64bit VMs.

Comment: It's enabled, can you give more details about using different processors, like which one and what else need to be setup to get it working?